# Select only td-elements in HTML table with specific column name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table with class `.info`, and I want to set the background color of all `td` elements, only in column `Amount`, where the value is `" "` to red.

The part of setting the color is done like this

```js
    $(document).ready(colorMissingPayment);
    function colorMissingPayment() {

        $(".info td").each(function () {
            var value = $(this).text();

            if (value == " ") {
                $(this).css("background-color", "red")
            };
        });
    };
```

but that targets all `td` elements in the table; how do I target a specific column/`th`? An example would be

```html
<table class="info">
    <tr>

        <td>
            <table>
                <h4 align="center">2021</h4>
                <tr>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th style="width:500px">Notes</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> </td>
                    <td>Hello</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 200</td>
                    <td>Monday</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>500+500 </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: use $(".info td:nth-child(columnNumber)") $(".info td:nth-child(1)") select first column

Comment: Find the index of the column containing "Amount", then use [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class to select the column. Notice, that `h4` is not permitted content in [`table` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just target table element with class selector `.info` then find all `td` that are `first-child`, then filter them by text content (note: even if in your HTML is space, textContent returns empty string). Finaly set background color with `jQuery.css`. Alternatively you can define `CSS` rule and use `jQuery.addClass`.

```js
$(document).ready(colorMissingPayment);
    function colorMissingPayment() {
        $(".info").find("td:first-child").filter( (i,o) => o.innerText === "")
          .css("background-color", "red");
    };
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="info">
    <tr>

        <td>
            <table>
                <h4 align="center">2021</h4>
                <tr>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th style="width:500px">Notes</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> </td>
                    <td>Hello</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 200</td>
                    <td>Monday</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>500+500 </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

How much legacy support do you want? There is a new browser css selector called `:has` that can help with this.

You'll still need a bit of JavaScript though:

```js
$(document).ready(colorMissingPayment);
function colorMissingPayment() {
    $(".info td").each(function () {
        const value = $(this).text();

        if (value.trim() === '') {
            $(this).addClass('is-empty')
        };
    });
};
```

```css
.info table tr:has(td.is-empty) td:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[Demo](https://flems.io/#0=N4IgzgpgNhDGAuEAmIBcIB0sxhAGhADMBLGXVAbVADsBDAWwjUwAt56p8RYB7axfswA88WgCMYAAlhRaOALwAdEMWqEeygHyLqkvZJEAnbdR37zB+EhMXbl8TBt3nQlgBZJtKMQDm1JdwQ-BCGWgBMAAxhAIxCAPTuTs62RknJLvAsmgCC9DwArvzxmWnpKZmSYPAAnjABAO7ESJmoAKwREQAOAB5aAHI8iGDFWWZl5sXGY+N6qdMzE1aaBnFL8wuzSwAS0FA8xdbrZZOlx-BTuhuL1pKREQenCyLWALJ8SLTVD0fpJz-Jc0uV021naEQA1GCVmsgcDnppvrDxn8kXZig4II9oYdTLCUeiJJidFxIDAEMQ+OQQGEAOyoCIgAC+eBoDCY6AwACtcAReMFBOgACQACiQPFg+UY-AAlBhDBBaEhqsLeHtDC9iDhVD4AAqfKXwaUAbh0hEK5L40h4ao1Wuouv1QXgwulkmAOnmIuUGFU6kkVmUsoVsBYwrN1Atuhdbv+fKqkgAbl58hBJPJJCLMprZYhus7jR7UXpiIRJMKk1AUxhzsR6NH5A3JAByJuu91FiyZljZjCKpAAYVkOGFTc1AFoIPROjVW-9GSbYYyC9R5yToHB4BTqFTohFUGEmSyQHRGMwsDguHyBPBmFYY5cxDxDEgQqhJNEepVrU1JBJaLAAGsF0ZQsfTUHh-Qxf1DFQFg5GFKwfTACcpxqV0rFQEhDCqMcQ1IJB7z0MR-wAnxDAKagkFw60nzfeUkGAtcyU3SlmAANlQaIxzcekmQAXQIbxqAA8gqGPNlmE5ABHFNDGqLh8kMTh0DYeBOjAVA4jiQpOlIrAeHoOJpNk6oAAEAGYMDYjBzLiJBNXgIyZJCaouR5EAak6dlwFgQxiGnfjGSAA)

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the wrong element.

```
  $(".info td").each(function () {
            var value = $(this).text();
   }
```

$(this) should return every `td` element.

It is unclear what do you mean by the value of column Amount? I suggest adding id's to your elements. That way you can target a specific column. for example:

```
<tr>
   <th id="ID_amount">Amount</th>
   <th style="width:500px">Notes</th>
</tr>

    $(".info #ID_column").each(function () {
        var value = $(this).text();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.info tr>td:nth-child(1):empty {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="info">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th style="width:500px">Notes</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> 200</td>
          <td>Monday</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>500+500 </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

You can achive this by just using css.
Note space inside the "td" is removed.